# How to authenticate to a VM using Vagrant up?

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, authentication, vagrant

**Authentication failure during Vagrant Up, while vagrant ssh and ssh vagrant@localhost -p2222 works**

I would like to execute a shell script using Vagrant at boot. Vagrant is unable to Authenticate, while the VM has been started using `vagrant up`:

```
c:\temp\helloworld>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'helloworld'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: helloworld_default_1398419922203_60603
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Error: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Error: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Error: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Error: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    ...
```

After executing `CTRL + C` it is possible to authenticate to the VM using `vagrant ssh` and `ssh vagrant@localhost -p2222`

**Vagrant file**

I use the default Vagrantfile and I only changed the hostname:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "helloworld"
  ...
```

**Vagrant version**

```
c:\temp\helloworld>vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.5.1
```

**Question**

How to authenticate to VM using `vagrant up`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was caused because no Public key reside on the Vagrant box. One of the following two options solves the issue.

The first option is to create a new Vagrant box using Packer. Add the [following snippet](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/packer-vagrant-linux/src/d0359d7e64e25a4ca6c2cfe53da80fb79d0dc8c4/ubuntu-12.04-amd64.json?at=master) to the json file and build the Vagrant box.

```
"provisioners": [{
    "type": "shell",
    "scripts": [
      "scripts/vagrant.sh"
    ]
}]
```

The content of this [vagrant script](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/packer-vagrant-linux/src/d0359d7e64e25a4ca6c2cfe53da80fb79d0dc8c4/scripts/vagrant.sh?at=master) is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum install wget -y

mkdir /home/vagrant/.ssh
wget --no-check-certificate \
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub' \
    -O /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R vagrant /home/vagrant/.ssh
chmod -R go-rwsx /home/vagrant/.ssh
```

The second option is to repackage (`vagrant package`) the Vagrant box once the following commands specified [here](http://williamwalker.me/blog/creating-a-custom-vagrant-box.html) have been run:

```
mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.ssh
wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub -O /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 0700 /home/vagrant/.ssh
chmod 0600 /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R vagrant /home/vagrant/.ssh
```

Comment: This worked for me! For those wondering, this makes Vagrant generate a new secure key, instead of using the old invalid one(if it even has one).

Answer (score 5):

**First, try:** to see what *vagrant private key* in you machine config

```
$ vagrant ssh-config
```

Example:

```
$ vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile C:/Users/konst/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh_config.html

**Second, do:**
Change content of file *insecure_private_key* with content of your own system *private key*

Answer (score 1):

I also could not get beyond:

default: SSH auth method: private key

When I used the VirtualBox GUI, it told me there was an OS processor mismatch.

To get vagrant up progressing further, in the BIOS settings I had to counter-intuitively:

Disable: Virtualisation

Enable: VT-X

Try toggling these setting in your BIOS.

Comment: Enabling Virtualization from BIOS resolved my issue related "Vagrant SSH"

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the scripts I see use this to pull the public key:

```
curl -L https://raw.github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub -o /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The issue I've seen is that the github SSL cert is for `www.github.com`, not `raw.github.com`. Therefore, you end up getting a `400` error.  You can verify this by looking at the contents of the `/home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Try using the `-k` option to ignore the SSL cert check:

```
curl -L -k https://raw.github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub -o /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your VM has network access. In case you use Virtual Box, get in your machine setting, network tab and make sure your Cable Connected is checked.